# Can I make web page look as pop up?

Tags: jquery, popup

I have created webpage and I am calling it from Jquery function. Technically I used {info} as image button and I am replacing with it with .aspx so that it is redirecting to that page.

.replace("${info}","/_layouts/webpage.aspx");

The web page is opening in new browser window. Is there any way that I could make it as pop up so I can place it anywhere in the page. That is to get rid off the toolbar address bar etc. It should look like a pop up.

Can anyone help me regarding this. Thanks in advance. I guess I provided the enough info. If not, please ask me.. May be next time I make it clearer.

2#(extend)
I am already using pop up..and I want to display another pop up on that which is having some server controls. Frankly I am new to jquery. I was thinking like I can create a.aspx page and after that I can modify it to as look like as pop up. or making it as fancy box.

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a modal popup. I like to use [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) for this type of functionality. That said there are a large variety of alternative [modal jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/modal) that will also work.

Comment: Nice. I was using http://plugins.jquery.com/project/facebox ... Might have to switch if ColorBox is smaller and faster.

Comment: jQueryUI also has a modal with `dialog`. I use that since I use jQueryUI often.

Comment: I am already using pop up..and I want to display another pop up on that which is having some server controls. Frankly I am new to jquery. 
I was thinking like I can create a.aspx page and after that I can modify it to as look like as pop up.