# Asp.net: How to get a page to appear like a pop up (smaller screen)?

Tags: asp.net

A put a ancor tag on a page. When I click it, I want the target page to appear smaller (i.e. 200px x 300px) just on top of the origin page.

```
<a href="Destination.aspx">Destination</a>
```

After I post back, I want the Destination page to desappear.

Thanks for helping

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106106/can-i-make-web-page-look-as-pop-up**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I click it, I want the target page to appear smaller (i.e. 200px
>   x 300px) just on top of the origin page

You can open it with `window.open`

```
<a onclick="openPopup();">Destination</a>

function openPopup()
{
    window.open("Destination.aspx","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
}
```

> After I post back, I want the Destination page to desappear.

1. Define a hidden field in Destination.aspx.

   ```
   <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnHidePopup" value="" />
   ```
2. In postback of Destination.aspx after which you want the popup to disappear, set value of hidden field to "true" or something you like

   ```
    hdnHidePopup.Value = "true";
   ```
3. On load of popup add this javascript, could be just before the ending tag of body.

   ```
     <script type="text/javascript">
          hdnHidePopup = document.getElementByID('<%= hdnHidePopup.ClientID %>');
          if(hdnHidePopup .value == "true")
          {
               hdnHidePopup.value = "";
               window.close();       
          }
       </script>
   ```